# Is there going to be a friendly Unity settings window?

Tags: unity, 11.04

Currently, as far as I am aware, you need to use the **CompizConfig Settings Manager** application to play with the Unity configuration settings.

While this makes sense, from a technical point of view, it requires the user to know about the settings manager, install it, and then find the Unity options within it. Not very user friendly.

Is there a user friendly configuration application planned that will offer all the configuration options in an *easy-to-use for new people* fashion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously, application like this will be developed some day (unless Canonical dumps Unity).

For now, it's not coming. 11.04 is not helping with this at all. I couldn't find anything related to this from [ubuntu Brainstorm](http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/?keywords=unity&tags=). There doesn't seem to be any bugs filed, so most probably it will not be be fixed anytime soon.

Comment: Mind if I try to correct some English mistake?

Comment: @Oxwivi: I don't mind at all, feel free to (always a good idea).

Comment: I submitted an edit, if it's accepted, have a look at the changes.